# How to make 'Card works like Suggestion' in dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

The text in the Suggestion helps to move the next intent that has the text of Suggestion. 
In the example of below, if the user click that button, the intents would move to the other intents that have 'dirrecion' as training phrase.

```
agent.add(new Suggestion(`dirrecion`));
```

But I want to make this same thing with 'Card'.
So I made like below code seeing doucments of Dialogflow. But it doesn't work.
Could you give me the solution?

```
  agent.add(new Card({
      title: `temperature`,
      imageUrl: wikipediaTemperatureImageUrl,
      text: `how are you`,
      //buttonText: 'Temperature Wikipedia Page',
      buttons: [
      {
        postback: `move`,
        text: `Card Link Title`
      }]
    })
  );
```

Comment: Hi. Did you solved that?